# How to analyze python dataframe and to count how many times a string occurs in a column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a python DataFrame and I want to analyze it.

```
columns=['User ID','Activity','Time Stamp','X-Axis','Y-Axis','Z-Axis']
input_data = pd.read_csv('walkingcupstairscdownstairs.txt',delimiter=',',names=columns)
```

The output is like this:

[image]

There are several activities in `Activity` column e.g jogging, running etc. i want to know how many times jogging or walking occurs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
input_data.Activity.value_counts()
```

Example:

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'Activity': np.random.choice(['Jogging', 'walking'], 10), 
                           'x':np.random.randn(10)})

>>> input_data
  Activity         x
0  walking -0.318043
1  walking -0.590098
2  walking -0.146811
3  Jogging  0.530030
4  Jogging  0.292955
5  walking  0.872765
6  walking  1.028513
7  Jogging -1.465817
8  Jogging  0.981183
9  walking -2.780214

>>> input_data.Activity.value_counts()
walking    6
Jogging    4
Name: Activity, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using numpy's unique function:

```
import numpy as np
np.unique(input_data['Activity'].values, return_counts=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`input_data.Activity.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get each unique value in the Activity column of the dataframe and the total number of times it shows up.

If you want a more general description about number of unique values, top value, top value occurance, etc., you can use [`input_data.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html) and look at the results for your Activity column instead.